# Jquery Append an image to the list will not open

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, image-gallery, photoswipe

I trying to use photoswipe within jquery mobile.
When I add an image in the list it works fine, the image will nicely open in the special image viewer.

```
    <ul class="gallery" id="pictures" >
    <li class="s1"><a href="images/no_photo.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

But when I append with JQuery an image then It added to the list but It won't open it the special image viewer.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Too little information. Maybe you could add also jQuery code and photoswipe I do not know photoswipe and how it exactly works. I will try answer based on information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The important things are actual loaded DOM elements. When you add image manually, they will presumably load earlier in DOM than those added by jQuery. You probably get images with photoswipe after pre-jQuery DOM modifactions, but before jQuery-driven DOM modifications. Make sure that things are done in a right order.

Comment: What is the right order?
First I load the <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery"> ect ect. 
After that I append an Image to the <ul class="gallery" id="pictures" > list

Comment: Please post you code. When you alert $("#pictures img").length right before opening in image viewer does the count include added image?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try data-role="listview" on the list and then do a listview refresh after adding it using jquery. do try it